# Nuxt-3: 404 Error page does not work in production

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxtjs3

I am working on a project, and I add `error.vue` to the root directory. This will render error page on `development` mode. But in `production` mode when we go on some random route it says **"No input file specified"**.

Anyone knows why this will not work in Production.

Below you can clearly see. The error page show in development but not in Production

**ON PRODUCTION MODE**

[image: error page on production]

**ON DEVELOPMENT MODE**

[image]

Comment: How does your nuxt config file look like? Does it work if you build locally? Which commands do you run locally to try that? Where do you host your code?

Comment: My code host on Laravel Forge. Run `npm run generate` command on both local and host. But the thing is whenever I run `npm run generate` doesn't matter I run this command on local or this command run in server it's always return **No Input file specified** and right now in nuxt.config.ts there is no configuration about error page or handling